# How do I associate these two objects correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

What I have:

```
class Map < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :connections
end
```

this works fine. I have two other models, `Connection` and `System`. Each Connection has a `from` attribute and a `to` attribute, both of which I want to be `System` objects.

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :map

    belongs_to :system, :class_name => "System", :foreign_key => "from"
    belongs_to :system, :class_name => "System", :foreign_key => "to"
end

class System < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :connections, foreign_key: "from"
    has_many :connections, foreign_key: "to"
end
```

This is where I'm at now. Before I was under the impression that `Connection` would `has_one :from, :class_name "System"` but that made rails look for a connection_id column in the System table.

This isn't working though.

```
@map.connections.each do |con|
    con.from.name #nomethod 'name' for FixNum error here
    con.to.name   #nomethod 'name' for FixNum error here
end
```

This however, does work.

```
@map.connections.each do |con|
    System.find(con.from).name
    System.find(con.to).name
end
```

I was just sorta working around this up until this point but I want this stuff associated properly before things get more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give any observer the reason this worked - when you set [ActiveRecord associations in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations), you're actually creating another method / attribute for your model to use

For example, when you define the association as `:system`, you'll be able to call `@object.system` in your view / controller / model. However, this also means this method is occupied - preventing you from being able to use it again (otherwise it gets overwritten)

What you discovered was that, instead of calling your associations `system`, calling them `from` and `to`, your associations will be handled correctly, giving you the ability to call `@object.from` and `@object.to`

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, this will definitely save me in the future as I wasn't 100% sure why this worked. I almost went to the trouble of actually just writing a from and to method into my model that referenced a from_id and to_id column to do a lookup and return a System, but since that's all the association is doing it makes perfect sense that I can't have two 'system' methods on my model.

Answer (score 1):

PRAISE THE SUN!!!

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :map

    belongs_to :from, :class_name => "System", :foreign_key => "from"
    belongs_to :to, :class_name => "System", :foreign_key => "to"
end
```